# Different appearance of Custom UIToolbar as inputAccessoryView on iOS6 device & simulator

Tags: ios-simulator, ios6, uitoolbar

I am trying to have a transparent UIToolbar as the inputAccessoryView of a UITextField in my iOS6 universal app.

When run on an iOS6 iphone, the toolbar appears transparent but has a top border. And this happens only on iOS6 iphone. Not on an iOS6 ipad device, not on iOS6 ipad simulator, not even on iOS6 **iPhone simulator**. Here are screenshots of device and simulator...

[image: iOS6 device screenshot]

[image: iOS6 Simulator screenshot]

Here is my code...

```
// Transparent Toolbar.m

@implementation TransparentToolbar
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [[UIColor clearColor] setFill];
    CGContextFillRect(context, self.bounds);
}
@end

// ViewController.m

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "TransparentToolbar.h"

@interface ViewController () {
    TransparentToolbar *_accessoryView;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize textField;
- (TransparentToolbar *)_accessoryView
{
    if (!_accessoryView) {
        _accessoryView = [[TransparentToolbar alloc] init];
        [_accessoryView sizeToFit];
        [_accessoryView setTranslucent:YES];

        UIBarButtonItem *flexButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];

        UIButton *resignKeyboardButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoDark];
        [resignKeyboardButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44)];
        [resignKeyboardButton setTitle:@"DONE" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [resignKeyboardButton addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapResignKeyboardButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        UIBarButtonItem *resignKeyboardBarButton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:resignKeyboardButton];

        NSArray *itemsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexButton, resignKeyboardBarButton, nil];
        [_accessoryView setItems:itemsArray];
    }

    return _accessoryView;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [textField setInputAccessoryView:[self _accessoryView]];
}

- (void)didTapResignKeyboardButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)aButtonItem
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
@end
```

What could be going wrong over here?